# Regexp to create proxy class

Tags: java, regex, proxy

I need to create a proxy for a class. I do not have access to the concrete subject but only to the subject interface. I have also a factory method to create the instance of the original implementation.

If I use Eclipse I can get a stub for each method:

```
@Override
public R1 method(T1 p1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
}
```

I need to create implementation like this:

```
@Override
public R1 method(T1 p1) {
    return instance.method(p1);
}
```

Because there are a lot of methods I used regexp with search and replace. Search for:

```
public ([a-z,A-Z,\.]*) ([a-z,A-Z]*)\(([a-z,A-Z]* ([a-z,A-Z]*))?\) \{\r\n([ ,\t]*)// TODO Auto-generated method stub\r\n[ ,\t]*return [0-9,a-z,A-Z]*\;
```

And replace with:

```
public \1 \2\(\3\) \{\r\n\5return instance\.\2\(\4\);
```

Is there a better solution?

Another problem comes with methods that take more params:

```
@Override
public R1 method(T1 p1, T2 p2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

The only solution I found is to have a different search-replace pairs for each number of params. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Are you avoiding dynamic proxies because the overhead would be too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easisest solution would probably to just use and IDE. For example in Netbeans 7 you could write the following skeleton:

```
public class MyProxy implements SomeInterface {
    private SomeInterface instance;

}
```

Then you place your curson inside the class, hit `ALT` and `Insert`, choose "delegate method", select all methods of the interface and click on generate.

Another, more dynamic, possibility would be to use the [java.lang.reflect.Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class of the jdk. This allows you to define a class at runtime that implements a given interface:

```
public static SomeInterface create() {
    return (SomeInterface)Proxy.newProxyInstance(MyProxy.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{SomeInterface.class}, new InvocationHandler() {
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            if ("method1".equals(method.getName())) {
                // Some special logic for this method
                return null;
            } else {
                // delegate all other methods
                return method.invoke(proxy, args);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry maybe my question is not clear. Although your answer is correct (and useful by the way because I didn't know this feature of  Netbeans 7) what I was really asking was a regexp. So it was more about the creation of a regexp to do it. Because I thought I was going to make it but I didn't so I was wondering if someone more expert than me on regexp could do it.

Comment: Ok, I thought it was a "I'll use a regexp, now I have two problems" type of question :)